# Do Until Loop Skipping Row 1

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I wrote a basic loop that works well, but I need it to ignore row 1 in case there are numerical headers (I previously used On Error Resume Next for String Headers, but I do not think it was the best way to handle the situation). Basically, I would like the loop to start at the second row.

```
Sub DoTest()


Dim i As Long
i = 1

Do



Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1) / Cells(i, 2)

i = i + 1


Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the line `i=1` to `i=2`

You should probably use a while loop, as you are currently trying to carry out the division before checking that the first row is non-empty.   You probably also need Cells.Value

```
Sub DoTest()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 2

    while not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) And not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value / Cells(i, 2).Value

        i = i + 1

    wend

    Range("C1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Tested and works--thanks! I also added an "On Error Resume Next" line, so it does not stop when it hits a division by zero issue. I'll check the box once the timer lets me.

Comment: just make absolutely sure you want to skip errors silently, "on error resume next" can be very dangerous in the wrong situations!

Comment: That's a good point. I modified it to use a simple IF THEN statement instead. Thanks!